# How to disable all styles for specific group of elements

Tags: javascript, html, css

is it possible to disable css styles for specific group of html elements?

To be more specific, I have html document and many css styles and I want to set default css for some elements (or remove/disable all styles for those elements).

Is there any way to do this using html/css/javascript? Setting all styles to default one by one takes time.

In addition I can say that it can be done by nesting part of code to iframe (because it doesn't inherit styles) but it is not much pretty way at all.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a class to the `<body>` tag?

**HTML**

```
<body class="default-theme">
  <p> ... </p>
  <ul>
    <li> .. </li>
  <ul>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
body.default-theme p {
   ... default settings ...
}

body.default-theme li {
  .. more css ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How are the elements grouped?  Is it by a particular class name?  If so you could do the following to clear out the style's or set them to a particular value

```
var all = document.getElementsByTagName('theClass');
for (var index in all) {
  var element = all[index];
  element.style = {};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you control the stylesheet, then you can just make all the styles depend upon a master class in the body element.  Then, you can turn all those rules on/off by simply adding or removing that class from the body element.

Suppose the class name is "master".  When the "master" class name is on the body element like this:

```
<body class="master">
```

then all these rules will be in force:

```
.master .selected {color: blue;}
.master #breadcrumb {color: red;}
```

If you then remove the "master" class from the body tag with script, all those rules will stop being applied instantly.

Obviously, you don't have to use the body tag.  You can use any common parent object of all the effected elements.